# Suggestion for modern algebra textbook

Tags: reference-request

I am trying to self-study abstract/modern algebra. I am currently trying to learn from Josephn Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra 7th edition* and free lecture notes from the internet.

So are there any other good textbooks for reference? Or anything better than Gallian's?

Comment: Abstract Algebra by. Dummit & Foote for a slightly more rigorous Algebra introduction and if you're up for a challenge, Lang's Algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend Michael Artin's *[Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130047635)* along with these [course materials](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra). You can also find supplementary materials (exercises, solutions, & notes) [here](http://abel.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/122/02/html/index.html).

The other canonical choice is usually Herstein's *Topics in Algebra.*

A book similar to Artin, but more leisurely, is Vinberg's *A Course in Algebra.*

For group theory, I have really been enjoying the first 100 pages of Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups.* It is quite readable!

And if you know a bit of algebra already, you might try Aluffi's *Algebra Chapter 0.* It is nonstandard (some use of categories from the start), but a pleasure to read. Plus, it's free!

If you're only looking for a reference, then I would have to say Dummit & Foote, as well. But as a main text... *meh.* But there are solutions for many exercises [here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/aadf/).